# How to convert a sentence to morse code using if statements

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is a sample of my program. I'm including else if statements for all the letters in the alphabet. Also the 10 before continue is on columns 4 and 5.

The first error I'm getting is saying `Invalid radix specifier "or" at (2) for typeless constant at (1)`, with 2 being the O in OR and 1 being the first quotation in "A", "B", etc.

The second error is saying the same thing but with the 1 being at the second quotation in "a", "b", etc.

And my third and final error is saying `Invalid form for ELSE IF statement at (^)` with the carrot being at the end of each statement.

I'm assuming these have to do with the fact that I'm just using the wrong syntax for If, ELSE IF, and DO; but searching the internet hasn't helped me find the correct syntax.

```
  program p1

  integer j
  integer sentenceSize
  character sentence*72

  print *, "Enter the size of the sentence you are converting: "
  read *, sentenceSize
  print *, "Enter the sentence you would like to convert: "
  read(*,'(A)') sentence
  DO 10, sentenceSize
  IF (sentence(i:i) == "A" OR "a")
  print *, ".-"
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == "B" OR "b")
  print *, "-..."
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == 'C' OR 'c')
  print *, "-.-."
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == "D" OR "d")
  print *, "-.."
  print *, " "
10   continue
```

Comment: You *really* can't find the correct syntax for fortran `if` and `do` on the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your program . Your DO loop is missing i=1. You need to put THEN after the IF and ELSE IF statements. A logic OR is .OR. Each OR'd item must be an expression (x == a .OR. y == c) not (x == a .OR. c). You need to terminate the IF-ELSE-THEN block with and END IF. And your program must end with END.

```
  program p1

  integer j
  integer sentenceSize
  character sentence*72

  print *, "Enter the size of the sentence you are converting: "
  read *, sentenceSize
  print *, "Enter the sentence you would like to convert: "
  read(*,'(A)') sentence
  DO 10 i=1, sentenceSize
  IF (sentence(i:i) == "A" .OR. sentence(i:i) == "a") THEN
  print *, ".-"
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == "B" .OR. sentence(i:i) == "b") THEN
  print *, "-..."
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == 'C' .OR. sentence(i:i) == 'c') THEN
  print *, "-.-."
  ELSE IF (sentence(i:i) == "D" .OR. sentence(i:i) == "d") THEN
  print *, "-.."
  END IF
  print *, " "
10   continue
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never used Fortran before. I realized my mistake with the THEN almost immediately, but couldn't find syntax on the .OR.

Comment: I would suggest a function to upper or lower case it all. You probably want an ELSE at the end to 'bark out' any undefined text.